# Excel - How To count(*) and groupby similar to SQL

Tags: sql, excel, count, group-by

I'm looking for a way to perform a SQL type command in Excel.  I need to get a count of each string in a column without knowing the string's text before hand.

Here's some sample data, I want to get a count of each Name.

```
Name
----
A
B
C
A
D
B
```

IN SQL I'd

```
SELECT Name, count(*)
FROM @table
group by Name
```

And I'd expect to get

```
Name | Count
-----|------
A    | 2
B    | 2
C    | 1
D    | 1
```

How can I perform this operation in Excel?

Comment: research the COUNTIF function in Excel

Comment: I looked at COUNTIF and it seems that you need to specify the string you're looking for.  In my situation I am looking for all strings, but it is unreasonable to have to create a COUNTIF statement for each string in my column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go with the pivot tables that give you some options to analyze your data. There is a good example with explanation on this website: http://www.contextures.com/pivottablecountunique.html

Comment: Thanks.  This does what we need and more